# Use API as a data source for Apache Superset

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, business-intelligence, apache-superset

While Superset supports a lot of data sources, currently an API source can't be used as a data source. We want to use API as a data source for better security and access control in a multi-tenancy deployment. We did find integration of GraphQL API as data source here : https://github.com/cancan101/graphql-db-api and it uses https://github.com/betodealmeida/shillelagh to do this. Is there any such already done implementation for a HTTP/HTTPS API call which we can directly integrate into Superset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect Superset to external APIs like Google Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612340/how-to-connect-superset-to-external-apis-like-google-analytics)

Comment: Added [tag:python] because Apache Superset requires it to run and to do the API calls.